# What does a catalog mean in Presto?

Tags: hive, presto

I understand the concept of DB and schemas within a DB and tables in a schema. Where does a catalog fit in this whole space. Does this extend to hive as well ?

Answer (score 4):

Presto accesses data via connectors, which are mounted in catalogs. The connector provides all of the schema and tables inside of the catalog. 
For example, the hive connector maps each hive database to a schema, so if the hive connector is mounted as the hive catalog

Catalog is mount point.